# Return null value in EF6 query with sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using Sp to produce some logic and return a table object.If no object found i just simply return null of a entity

```
CREATE proc SpDealerDistributionOracle 
(
    @DealerCode varchar(50),
    @imei varchar(50)
) 
as
BEGIN
    if (some logic)
        select  top 1 * from tblBarCodeInv
    else 
        select null;
END
```

Works fine ..But when I wrote query in EF 6 like this

```
 tblBarCodeInv returnValue = null;
 using (var db=new RBSYNERGYEntities())
 {
       String query = String.Format("SpDealerDistributionOracle 'DealerCode','101001'");
       returnValue = db.Database.SqlQuery<tblBarCodeInv>(query).FirstOrDefault();                  
 }
 return returnValue;
```

It throws an exception.

I simply want to return a object if not found return null and do some logic in C#.Can anybody help??

Comment: But i need to use Sp.As you know Sps are precompiled and Functions are not.Their may be 50000+ plus operation per day .So this is better to use sp

Comment: Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

Comment: This is use full but  not my question is .I just return null if no entry found ..When i return it it throws exception that RecId(Primary key) is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your procedure to still return a "collection" in both cases. However in the second case it will be an empty collection and thus will reach the "Default" of the `FirstOrDefault`

```
BEGIN    
    if (some logic)
        select  top 1 * from tblBarCodeInv
    else 
        SELECT TOP 0 * from tblBarCodeInv 
END
```

Comment: `{"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'RBSYNERGYModel.tblBarCodeInv'. A member of the type, 'RecID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."}` is found on my machine

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash - I recommend that you edit your question to add the original error message - that is what people will look for on google - and that is how your question will help in the future

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash - Glad to help :)